# How to override JavaScript safely

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation-6

My goal : Prevent Dropdrop from closing if an input control in focus inside the drop down pane.

I've found that if I comment out the following lines, it prevents the dropdown pane from closing in all cases. So, I've isolated the code which I want to modify.

https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/v6.5.0-rc.3/js/foundation.dropdown.js#L161-L165
https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/v6.5.0-rc.3/js/foundation.dropdown.js#L172-L176

I'm using gulp/npm workflow. I don't want to modify the original files inside node_modules.

Question: How do I safely override `_events` in the `Dropdown` class?
Should I override the entire property?

```
Foundation.Dropdown.prototype._events = function(){
  // my modified code here?
}
```

The above method works but I was wondering if it's the right way.
Is there any other way through which I could just turn off the events on the specific elements?

Comment: _events is a method right ?

Comment: I suggest you to `extend` the Foundation.Dropdown class with your own implementation and use that.  You can safely override the _events function there without breaking the original Foundation.Dropdown behaviour.

Comment: @82Tuskers : yes _events is a method. Oh, I see what I did there. Correcting it. Thanks!
@zfor : Thanks, I'll check extend too.

What's the difference between using
`Foundation.Dropdown.prototype._events = function() { ... }`
vs
`My_Dropdown extends Dropdown { ... }` ?

Comment: @PrathameshGharat If you override the `Foundation.Dropdown.prototype` you override the behaviour of every Dropdown component you're using. You might want to avoid that. If you create your own implementation by extending the Dropdown class, you can use your custom dropdown logic only when it's needed without affecting other dropdown components.